# Search box on advice page missing on mobile web

Tags: bug, new-users, mobile-safari, responsive-design

It’s pretty simple: compare [this page using desktop view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?) with the screenshots below of the mobile version:

[image]

[image]

What Shog calls the “[most important part](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377977/the-advice-shown-to-all-new-users-asking-questions-should-be-useful#comment657013_377977)” of the page is missing: the search bar. Also, while it’s possible to use the desktop site, the page isn’t responsive so it is unwieldy to use. I also wouldn’t even be able to easily access the desktop site because the footer is completely covered with that message.